# Generating gradient colors in python

Tags: python

Given N number of buckets, I would like to generate colors continuously on the rainbow (where n>=2):

[image]

For example, if n=2, the colors would be:

```
rgb(255,0,0) -->rgb(0,0,255)
```

If n=3, the colors would be:

```
rgb(255,0,0) --> rgb(0,255,0) --> rgb(0,0,255)
```

What would be a good way to generate these color codes?

Comment: The gradient is over hue values, so it would make sense to work e.g. with HSL rather than RGB.

Comment: @kaya3 got it. Maybe you could put that in an answer and show how to generate with HSL and that would answer the above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your rainbow gradient smoothly varies the hue from 0 degrees to 240 degrees (the hue of the pure blue colour). Therefore it will be easiest to work with e.g. HSL values rather than RGB values, so you can vary the hue while leaving the saturation and lightness constant.

The [colorsys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/colorsys.html) library allows conversion between different colour spaces, so you can use this to generate the RGB values along the rainbow gradient as you need. The `hls_to_rgb` function uses float values between 0 and 1, so `2/3` is the hue for blue, and the bright colours should have a lightness of `0.5` and a saturation of `1`.

```py
from colorsys import hls_to_rgb

def rainbow_color_stops(n=10, end=2/3):
    return [ hls_to_rgb(end * i/(n-1), 0.5, 1) for i in range(n) ]
```

The result is a list of `(r,g,b)` tuples.

Comment: thanks, this looks like the correct solution, and thanks for the clear explanation on this. I've tried a simple rgb approach as well in an answer (though I'll use your approach). Does my approach seem adequate, or is it missing a lot that I'm not noticing?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a little script to do so, using kaya3's suggestion about HSV. Was a fun little exercise.

```
import colorsys
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def spectrum(n : int):
    hsv = [(h, 1, 1) for h in np.linspace(0, 240/360, n)]
    rgb = [colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(*tup) for tup in hsv]
    defloat = lambda x: tuple((int(255 * i) for i in x))
    return [defloat(x) for x in rgb]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = 100
    rgb = np.array(spectrum(n))
    rgb = rgb.reshape((1, n, 3))
    rgb = np.tile(rgb, (n, 1, 1))
    plt.imshow(rgb)
    plt.show()
```

Which generates the following figure
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using the RGB scale, Red starts at `(255,0,0)` and the middle, Green, is at `(0,255,0)` and the end, Blue, is at `(0,0,255)`. We can move through the scale by starting at `(255,0,0)` and 'stepping' until we get to the end.

Let's say there are 256*2 steps to get from red to green (red goes from 256->0 and green goes from 0->256) and 256*2 to get from green to blue. This comes up to 1024 steps. Now we can divide 1024 by the number of buckets we want, `n`. Here's an example:

```
def generate_gradient_rgbs(num_buckets):
    rgb_codes = []
    step_size = 1024 / num_buckets
    for step in range(0,num_buckets):
        red = int(max(0, 255 - (step_size*step*0.5))) # step size is half of the step size since both this item goes down and the next one goes up
        blue = int(max(0, 255 - (step_size*0.5*(num_buckets-step-1))))
        green = (255 - red) if red else (255 - blue)
        rgb_codes.append((red, green, blue))
    return rgb_codes
```

> ```
>  >>> generate_gradient_rgbs(4)
> [(255, 0, 0), (127, 128, 0), (0, 128, 127), (0, 0, 255)]
> ```

Of course this is a starting point but for a quick-and-dirty way to get rgb's, this is a possible approach.

Comment: This solution has a couple of problems. Note how close together your two middle colours are, compared with how far apart they are from the other colours. Also note that (127,128,0) is quite a bit darker than the yellow in your original image.

Comment: @kaya3 those are good points, thanks for the feedback! Do you think it's possible to do something like the above with rgb, or is the only (good) solution here using hls?

Comment: You can, of course, do the calculations yourself; but you'll get the best results if you follow the formulae for HSL -> RGB conversion; see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#HSL_to_RGB

Answer (score 0):

For those of you looking for the transformation of a 2d grayscale image to rgb gradient in numpy, here is an efficient version:

```py
def value_to_gradient(value: int) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Transform a value between 0 and 255 to an RGB gradient.

    Parameters
    ----------
    value : int
        Value between 0 and 255.

    Returns
    -------
    gradient : np.ndarray
        1D NumPy array with shape (3,) representing the RGB gradient.
    """
    # Compute the RGB values of the gradient
    canvas = np.zeros((*value.shape, 3), dtype=value.dtype)
    # red
    canvas[value > 128, 0] = 2 * (value[value > 128] - 128)

    # green
    canvas[value < 128, 1] = 2 * (value[value < 128])
    canvas[value > 128, 1] = 255 - 2 * (value[value > 128] - 128)
    
    # # blue
    canvas[value < 128, 2] = 255 - 2 * (value[value < 128])
    return canvas
```